# Weird fault in circuit - Charge building up and blocking potentiometer?

Tags: audio, troubleshooting

I've made some inline headphone volume attenuators myself for live use, so that we have some volume control on our hip and don't have to wander over to the headphone amp, partly because I didn't want to shell out 60€ for a couple of Behringer Powerplays (also I didn't want the XLR input, I prefer a 3.5mm input) and partly because I like a challenge.

So I've made [this circuit](https://crcit.net/c/0a20890854974909a9fd2ceb60ea9f5d) (a little voltage divider with 1Kohm stereo potentiomers)

[image]

And, I'm experiencing a couple of problems, I'm pretty sure I've isolated it down to the potentiometer. For some reason the potentiometers get 'jammed', I don't know how else to describe it. The channel sometimes goes silent unless I bridge the contacts with a screwdriver, after that it seems to work just fine and I have no idea why this fixes it. It's like a charge builds up in the potentiometer and stops the signal travelling through. Does anyone have any suggestions why or possible solutions?

My potential idea is to bridge the contacts together and to ground with a large resistor (1MOhm or something), is this sensible?

Thanks.

Comment: In case there are DC volume loudness control voltages also passed between the devices, put a 10 uF (or bigger) capacitor in the potentiometer grounded lines.

Comment: I think it more likely the potentiometer wiper is losing contact and your screwdriver “bridging” jiggled it. Try “bridging” with an insulated object and see if this also fixes it. Also, how about a photo so we see the type of pot, soldering, etc.

Comment: What's the headphone load impedance and for how much power is the potentiometer rated? It might simply die because exceeding ratings.

Comment: I'd try skipping the ground connections entirely: a (up to) 1K series resistor should be enough to significantly attenuate (but not mute) the headphone level, assuming you're using low impedance (16-40 ohm) phones.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt It didn't seem to be, but I do remember that I fixed it once by percussive maintenance once I put the thing back together... With that in mind, does it mean a dodgy potentiometer? I'll try and get you a photo tomorrow, it's gone midnight here!

Comment: @Justme The pot [link]https://www.ebay.de/itm/2X-R16148-1B-2-A1K-Potentiometer-axial-1-Drehung-1k%CE%A9-63mW-20-THT-6mm-Metall-S)[/link] is rated at 63mA and the headphones I'm testing on are Sony MDR-7506, according to their website 63 Ohms, but also happens on other earphones with probably lower impedance.

Comment: Dodgy pot or dodgy solder joint, will await photo and your further ‘percussive’ testing.

Answer (score 1):

It's the wiper! Either it's losing contact, or the resistive material inside is deteriorating, I have personally faced the latter, and I'll tell you this, get a new potentiometer

Comment: Yeah, the description of the symptoms sounds quite consistent with a faulty/intermittent wiper contact...